# Como puedo meter un input type file en un popover de bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript

esto proporciona bootstrap:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content='<input type="text"/>'>
```

Popover on top

Esto aparece:

---

[image: al presionar el botón quier que aparezca el input correctamente para poder luego guardar en la BDD con php]

al presionar el botón quier que aparezca el input correctamente para poder luego guardar en la BDD con php.

ayuda por favor no me aparece nada si alguien conoce otra forma de hacerlo seria de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Mira si te sirve esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128425/contain-form-within-a-bootstrap-popover

Comment: Mira a ver si te sirve algo así, lo he hecho sin tener mucha idea de bootstrap 4 https://codepen.io/Brokhael/pen/KLPyMW

Comment: gracias amigo es mas o menos lo que busco pero falla el bootstrap

Comment: igual tratare de acoplarlo a lo que necesito, muchas gracias otra vez.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

necesitas agregar el atributo `data-html='true'`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-html='true' data-content='<input type="text"/>' >
```